# tensorflow backend in keras for video

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using keras with **tensorflow backend**,my data is **video**.

So now I have a problem with data dimension, I know **first channels** is for theano and **last channels** for tf. I  have problem where to put **number of frames**.

1. Is this true? **(number of samples,number of frames,img_rows,img_cols,channels)** -- for example:`(390,25,48,48,1)`
2. or is this true? **(number of samples,img_rows,img_cols,channels,number of frames)** -- 
   for example like this: `(360,48,48,1,25)`

Which one is true for keras with tf backend for video data? **1 or 2**?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras by itself defines its data format as `channels_last`. There is no need to worry about whether you're using theano or tensorflow. (You can change this either in convolutional layers or in the default settings at the file `<user>\.keras\keras.json`)

But this is valid mainly for images and other convolutional layers: `(img_row,img_cols,channels)`

As far as I know, there is no predefined format for video.

- When you are using recurrent layers, you will have `(batchSize,timeSteps,featuresPerStep)`
- When using 2D convolutions: `(batchSize, rows, columns, channels)`
- When using 1D convolutions: `(batchSize, length, channels)`

There is the possibility to use a layer wrapper called [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/), which will allow non recurrent layers to receive inputs with the additional `timeSteps` dimension just after the batch dimension: `(batchSize,timeSteps, ...other dimensions....)` -- It will replicate the wrapped layer for each time step.

So, a 2D convolutional layer with the time distributed wrapper would take inputs as: `(batchSize,timeSteps,rows,columns,channels)`